# How to add seconds on a datetime value in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I tried modifying the second property, but didn't work.

Basically I wanna do:

```
datetime.now().second += 3
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Have you checked out timedeltas?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
x = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=3)
x += timedelta(seconds=3)
```

Comment: Why you add twice ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add seconds to a datetime object. From the [docs](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/DateTime):

> A DateTime object should be considered immutable; all conversion and numeric operations return a new DateTime object rather than modify the current object.

You must create another datetime object, or use the product of the existing object and a timedelta.

Answer (score 0):

The datetime module supplies classes for manipulating dates and times.
But two different classes exist in the datetime:
the class datetime.datetime. This class combines dates and time.
the class datetime.timedelta: A duration expressing the difference between two date, time, or datetime instances to microsecond resolution.
datetime.second - method second returns second for the date, but it won't be a timedelta.
You should change type of class form datetime to timedelta.
example:

```
x = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=3)
```

After that you can use compound addition:

```
x += timedelta(seconds=3
```